# What happens if you make an offer on an already connected peer?

Tags: webrtc

So I am writing an app in which I switch from connecting 2 clients into connecting 3 clients to a server instead of each other in which I am defining when the 3rd client joins the 2 other clients will make a new offer. However this way, despite the fact that I can get them connected to server, the tracks that were added between the 1st and 2nd client is not sent to server and does not show as `ontrack`. What should I do to get the track from the first and 2nd peer? the tracks are already added, do I have to add the tracks again to the peer before making the offer from them?

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal to have the video from your 2 clients uploaded/processed on a server? If so you will need to a create a new PeerConnection on each client to connect with your server. You will then call `getUserMedia` and add your track again to this new PeerConnection.

WebRTC just allows you to establish a 1:1 connection. You can't communicate with two remote peers with one PeerConnection.

Comment: so I need a new const pc = new RTCPeerConnection() the 2nd time around?

Comment: Yep! Everytime you want to communicate with someone else you need to create a new RTCPeerConnection. It isn't exactly what you are building, but close to https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/08-applied-webrtc/#full-mesh